# Why do you multiply the two images to see the correlation?

Tags: image, pytorch, correlation

I have some questions about the CP Viton module:

```
feature_A = feature_A.transpose(2,3).contiguous().view(b,c,h*w)

feature_B = feature_B.view(b,c,h*w).transpose(1,2)

# perform matrix mult.
feature_mul = torch.bmm(feature_B,feature_A)
print(feature_mul.size()) #torch.Size([4, 192, 192])
```

at this code

1. For the multiplication of matrices, I don't know why they make it like b,h*w,h*w.
2. It is said that multiplying the shape of the image as follows is to extract the correlation, but I don't know why. I'm talking about the `bmm` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spatial correlation consists of computing the dot product of feature vectors of every `(feature_A[k,:,i], feature_B[k,:,j])` feature pair. As such you first need to flatten the spatial dimension which results in a dimension of size `h*w` on both tensors. Your two operands will have a shape of `(b, c, hw)`, and `(b, hw, c)`. As a result of applying `bmm`, you end up with a tensor shaped `(b, hw, hw)`

Comment: Thank you for the good answer. Thanks to you, I was able to understand the concept of image.
Can I ask you one more question?
I want to know why Making the three-dimensional form back into four dimensions and transposing it   like below code

i guess eventually  tring to make it into a correlated image(made by vector multiplying two images.) form having a channel as much as h*w, right? 

`correlation_tensor = feature_mul.view(b,h,w,h*w).transpose(2,3).transpose(1,2)
        # b,h*w,h,w`

Comment: Matrix multiplication works by reducing the "middle axis": as `(i,j) x (j,k) = (i,k)`. Cross-correlation works on a single matrix shaped `(c, hw)` so you need to tranpose it to get `(c, hw)` on one hand and `(hw, c)` on the other. Everything is *batched*, so utlimately you are working with an additional dimension on `axis=0`: `(b, c, hw)` and `(b, hw, c,)`